# What is French for Wine Box (not a case, but a vacuum sealed bag in a cardboard box)?

Tags: vocabulaire, alimentation

What is French for Wine Box (not a case, but a vaccuum sealed bag)?

In Calais wine shops if you ask for a wine box you get a wooden case with bottles inside.  In English supermarket a wine box is cardboard with something like this inside 
[image]

and with its outer packaging

[image]

Shockingly, it looks like the French have adopted an English term Bag-in-Box

https://www.vin-subtil.com/content/34-bib-vin

Surely not.

I'm trying to Google what the French say for wine boxes.

Comment: “Surely not”. And why not?

Comment: I thought there was a French minister banning English words to protect the French language.

Comment: Not really no. The *Académie Française* and the *Office Québecois de la Langue Française* do recommend alternatives, but no one is banning anything, and in France at least — where the linguistic pressure is historically weaker — not many people actually heed their recommendations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

French wine sellers call it too BIB and a suggested translation is [*outre à vin*](http://www.dico-du-vin.com/bib-bag-in-box/) but I wouldn't ask for an *outre à vin* in a wine shop.

Either use the old *[cubi](http://boutique.vins-descombe.com/vin-en-cubi.html)* (for *Cubitainer*) which would always be understood or better, prefer *[fontaine à vin](http://www.coteaux-des-baronnies.com/produits.php#text_BLOCK_RU8O3VVF5B)* which clearly rules out plain bottles and isn't associated with low quality wine like *cubi* might be.

A [reseller](http://semaq.com/) also suggests *carton cubi*, *carton fontaine à vin*, *carton bouteille*. The oqlf dictionary also has *[caisse outre](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8370424)* and *carton-outre*.

Answer (score 0):

As Jiliagre said, "wine box" could be translate in many ways : "fontaine à vin", "outre à vin", "cubi"...

If you would like to ask for a BIB in shop, [I advice you to use the world "cubi"](https://pinotbleu.com/content/89-conservation-vin-cubi-les-details-a-connaitre) which is the most used world in French for BIB :)